# 2 strings in 1 where one of the strings is $row related

Tags: php

I have a variable that gets the language from the URL (either jp or en)

```
$lang = $_GET["lang"];
```

And for each language I have a row in the database

```
$menu_name_jp=$row['menu_name_jp'];
$menu_name_en=$row['menu_name_en'];
```

How can I combine the `$lang` variable with the `$menu_name_` variable so I get a different variable according to the $lang

I have tried something like that but it doesn't work (of course :))

```
$menu_name="$menu_name_$lang";
```

**MORE INFORMATION**
I have tested the examples but id didnt work as because I also have a variable called just $menu_name with no lang in the end which serves for the default language. And what I am doing is that:

```
if ($lang=="df")
{
$menu_name=$menu_name;
}
else
{
$menu_name=$menu_name.'_'.$lang;
}
```

So, the result is that it just append the default menu_name with the lang. Like this

***HOME_jp***

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
echo $menu_name = ${'menu_name_'.$lang };
```

But rather I will suggest you to create an array such as,

```
$menu_name = array("jp" => $row['menu_name_jp'],"en" => $row['menu_name_en']);
echo $menu_name[$lang];
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FPaMLs)**.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks... I have learned something today :)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't get any simpler than this:

```
$menu_name = $row['menu_name_' . $lang];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the values using dot operator. Try with

```
$menu_name="menu_name_".$lang;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
${"menu_name_".$lang} = $row['menu_name_'.$lang'];
```

Then you can call it like this: `echo $menu_name_jp`

Answer (score 1):

That's what you need:

```
<?php

$menu_name_jp='one';
$menu_name_en='two';

$lang = 'jp';


echo ${'menu_name_'.$lang};
```